# Safari Background Gradient - Right side of gradient showing up 1px on left side

Tags: css, safari, background-color

I've changed the fade to color to red to make the issue more visible.  The 100% color on the gradient is bleeding in for 1 pixel on the left side of this div. This appears to be a Safari bug, but I'm wondering if anybody has a fix for this?

[image: Safari Background Gradient Issue]

Styles applied to this are as follows:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #007AC3 0%,#d30421 100%);
padding: 0 4.29929%;
width: auto !important;
background: #1575C5;
float: left;
display: block;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
letter-spacing: 0.04em;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: inherit;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
cursor: auto;
```

DOM:

```
<a class="menu-item" href="/About" target="_top">
    <div>
      <p>About</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: you may try to add : **repeat-y;** to background or reset background-clip

Comment: Actually I tried both and neither helped.  It's pretty clearly a Safari only bug as no other browser does this.

The fix was actually narrowing down the decimals in the padding to 4.29%

Answer (score 0):

Changing the padding to only 2 decimals fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I run into similar problem as @Fastmover.

I believe it has to do with the bug of Safari doing ceiling and flooring when calculate percentage based width and somehow the ending color appears at the beginning (which I believe doesn't really make sense!!).

In my case, I don't have padding, so I had a whacky way solving the problem by setting the beginning color & ending color as the same as background color. So it will look like (assuming the background color is white):

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0% #007AC3 1%,#d30421 99%, white 100%);
```

So even though it may appear on the other end, it "blend" well with the background and nobody will notice that...